# backand platform: what is the objects life cycle (or db trigger action)

Tags: javascript, backand

Because of the lack of precise documentation on Backand documents. I wonder what actually happens at each *before*,*during*,*after* stages in the Create, Update, Delete DB trigger object events .

What do I get in `backandCallback` arguments: `userInput`, `dbRow`, `parameters`, `userProfile`?

What happens if I update every one of them in each stage?

what the meaning of return value from the functions ..

And what happens if I terminate the execution of the action with exception in each stage?

Answer (score 2):

**Create - before**
`userInput` - you got all the keys that you send in the Post Data that exist in the schema minus keys of type collection . if you update that object the update will be part of the saved dbRow data.

`dbRow` - empty object. update it make not make effect

`parameters` - you got here any data that you send in Post Data. in JSON format even if it not part of the schema. update it make no effect

`userProfile` - you got here detail of login user `{username == useremail, role, app == appName, token== usertoken, requset == same as global requset object}`

make *exception* here cancel the creation, and return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client

**Create-During**

`userInput` - same as above. but update the object not have effect on saved object

`dbRow` - same as `userInput` Plus id keys. plus keys of type Collection exist with string value of the name of the entity collection they should point of (example : owner:"user" )

`parameters` - same as above

`userProfile` - same as above

*exception* here cancel the creation, and return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client

**Create - after**

`userInput` - same as above.

`dbRow` - same as above

`parameters` - same as above

`userProfile` - same as above

*exception* here **not** cancel the creation, but return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client.

It is good point for code that want ot be sure the object is already created

---

**Update - before**

`userInput` - keys that you send in Post data that exsist in the schema (include id btw ) minus keys of type collection . update the object reflect on the updated dbRow

`dbRow` - orginal dbRow data before the update. update the object not have any effect

`parameters` - all keys that you send on Post data in Json format

`userProfile` - same as creation process.

exception here cancel the update. and return exception string as a response to the requst from the client

**Update - during**

`userInput` - same as above. manipulate the object not make afftect on updated dbRow

`dbRow` - schema object as updated by the userInput keys ( `id` key will not be update event if it exist in userInput )

`parameters` - same as above

`userProfile` - same as above.

exception here cancel the update. and return exception string as a response to the requst from the client

**Update - after**

`userInput` - same as above.

`dbRow` - same as above

`parameters` - same as above

`userProfile` - same as above.

exception here **not** cancel the update. but return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client

---

**Delete - before**

`userInput` - empty object {}.

`dbRow` - orginal row as saved

`parameters` - empty object {}.

`userProfile` - same as Creation event.

exception here cancel the delete. and return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client

**Delete - during**

`userInput` - same as above.

`dbRow` - same as above

`parameters` - same as above

`userProfile` - same as above.

exception here cancel the delete. and return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client

**Delete - after**

`userInput` - same as above.

`dbRow` - same as above

`parameters` - same as above

`userProfile` - same as above.

exception here **not** cancel the delete. but return exception string as a Response to the Requst from the client

Comment: Importent note: during the create process if I attend to add sub object to another schema that have reference to current object you can do that just after `Create - after `. because  on the creation of the sub object if the current object not in the DB . some proceccs is stuck

Comment: 1. on create,  the parameters are sent in the querystring,

Comment: 2. on create, when changing the parameters in the JS action that effects the parameters in the rest of the JS action that follows